# Native Binding project fails with MTOUCH: error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-binding

Using objective sharpie I created a binding project for an internal Objective C library, the binding project includes three ios framework sources

[image]

The binding project builds fine and produces an output dll as expected, checking the output dll with iLSpy confirms that the native references are included in the dll. A demo app was created to test the binding, but the problem is I can not get the demo app to compile, it fails with

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "_IOS_DERIVED_CREDENTIALS", referenced from:           _IOS_STORAGE in
>   IdentosSDK(ios_storage.o)       "_OPENSSL_DERIVED_CREDENTIALS",
>   referenced from:           _OPENSSL_STORAGE in
>   IdentosSDK(openssl_storage.o)       "_OPENSSL_EC", referenced from:
>   _create_key_with_type in IdentosSDK(openssl_storage_identity.o)       "_PENDING_REGISTRATION", referenced from:
>   _to_initialized_state in IdentosSDK(id_start_state.o)

before finally failing with this

> MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol:
>   _IOS_DERIVED_CREDENTIALS. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly
>   linked in.     MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined
>   symbol: _OPENSSL_DERIVED_CREDENTIALS. Please verify that all the
>   necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are
>   properly linked in.

I have tried passing `gcc_flags` passed to mtouch as shown below

[image]

I know the framework in the binding project supports the appropriate architectures as running lipo -info libIdentosSDK.a produces: armv7 i386 x86_64 arm64

Not sure what else to do to fix this. Any help will be appreciated. The complete [build log](https://pastebin.com/8AbeQR4c)

```
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _IOS_DERIVED_CREDENTIALS. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _OPENSSL_DERIVED_CREDENTIALS. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _OPENSSL_EC. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _PENDING_REGISTRATION. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _add_events. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _asym_decrypt. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _asym_encrypt. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _asym_free. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _asym_sign. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _asym_verify. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _cleanup_events. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _create_event. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
MTOUCH : error MT5210: Native linking failed, undefined symbol: _create_event_bool. Please verify that all the necessary frameworks have been referenced and native libraries are properly linked in.
```

Comment: https://github.com/bitstadium/HockeySDK-Xamarin/issues/30 maybe help.

Comment: what did you do to this issue ? is it fix ?